# Tables, responcivity, css and google chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome

So here is simple page html, css, nothing else (no javascript, php)
http://tsiskreli.highlander.ge/cancel.htm

Here is the page in different browsers.
In firefox and IE while resizing table changes size fits to window, but in chrome no. Is it possible to add something to css to repair this bug?

http://s21.postimg.org/cwlnx2dtz/Screenshot_13.jpg

Comment: Please include relevant code within your question itself, not just a link.

Comment: once the browser width hits 480px it changes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `max-width` are wrong.

You have to change all the `max-width: 480px` to `max-width: 630px`, and then your problem will be solved.

(i have tested this and now it works with this values)

---

### **[Check this](http://paste.ofcode.org/HGYSLrzT9SE3QPMwi3swic)**